# Nuxt3 render mode on route page

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt3

Nuxt3 page route is default rendered on client side？My app page only first page is rendered on serverside，and other page is rendered on client side like vue router，is this normal？Can I get a page rendered by ssr using nuxtlink？

I tried，but every page using nuxtlink is rendered by client side，but I found，if I use "a" tag to navigate，the page will refresh and this page will be rendered by ssr.

Comment: Could you share minimal reproduction code? I tried to to [reproduce it](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-demo-9556168), but Nuxt worked well in both dev and prod modes.

Comment: A very simple demo inited by nuxi，only 2pages here in pages dir one is index.ts another is about.ts，nuxt.config.ts file is empty，only one line in pages/index.ts <template><NuxtLink to="/about">to about</NuxtLink></template>，and app.vue only has a NuxtPage tag

Answer (score 1):

You should use { ssr: true} for that page on  you nuxt.config.
There are different rendering mode in nuxt and you can see the its article here:

https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/rendering

As you can see you can choose different property for your different routes.

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  routeRules: {
    // Homepage pre-rendered at build time
    '/': { prerender: true },
    // Product page generated on-demand, revalidates in background
    '/products/**': { swr: 3600 },
    // Blog post generated on-demand once until next deploy
    '/blog/**': { isr: true },
    // Admin dashboard renders only on client-side
    '/admin/**': { ssr: false },
    // Add cors headers on API routes
    '/api/**': { cors: true },
    // Redirects legacy urls
    '/old-page': { redirect: '/new-page' }
  }
}
```

for example
ssr: boolean - Disables server-side rendering for sections of your app and make them SPA-only with ssr: false

if you use api and it changes during your work it is better to use this code

```
  if (process.client) {
///    do this
  }else{
///    do that
  }
```